# Meissner Effect and Lorentz Force Paradox?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

The Meissner effect expels magnetic field lines in a super conductor, see the picture below. Left is normal conducting, right is the superconducting state.

[image]

If I have a superconducting wire of radius $r_0$ now, the Meissner effect leads to $B(r<r_0)=0$. When I drive a current $J(r<r_0)=J_0$ this current leads to zero forces when calculating the force using the Lorentz force: $f=j\times B = 0$.

This would mean that all superconducting coils experience no forces. What am I missing here?

Comment: For condensed matter, there is also (since only 2 months ago!): https://materials.stackexchange.com/, but I agree with the answer you have already received here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A great question!

The answer is that there is a still a force of ${\bf I}\times {\bf B}_{\rm external}$ per unit length  of the wire. This is  because the ${\bf B}$ field does penetrate some distance (naturally this is called the *penetration depth*) into the supercondcuting wire, and, for reasons similar to the Meissner effect itself, this near-surface penetration depth region is also where the current carried by  the wire flows.  That the location of the current and strength of the penetrating ${\bf B}$ field conspire to give exactly the same answer for the force as if there were no Mesissner effect is not exactly obvious. It is, however,  a magnetic analogue of the statement that if you put a charge $Q$ on a conducting body and immerse the body in a uniform electric field ${\bf E}_{\rm external}$ then the force on the body is still exactly $Q {\bf E}_{\rm external}$ despite the fact that there is no ${\bf E}$ field inside the conducting body.